# How to add constraint `on-update-cascade` in Doctrine 2

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to introduce doctrine to an already started project. Now, we have this table which has an `ON UPDATE CASCADE` constraint. The question is, how can this be mapped to an entity?

I was expecting something like `onUpdate="CASCADE"` but doctrine has no such thing (despite the [docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-joincolumn) claiming so)

```
/**
 * @Id
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="ColumnA")
 * @JoinColumn(..., onDelete="CASCADE", onUpdate(?)="CASCADE")
 */
protected $columnA;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
/**
 * @Id
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="ColumnA")
 * @JoinColumn(..., cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
protected $columnA;
```

To fully understand how the cascade operations works in Doctrine2, read [this section](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations) in docs. I hope it helps.